# Regarding running threads in parallel and return after

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is a class that I wrote where the intent was that we create different threads from the main program which run in parallel and the main thread resumes execution after all the threads have finished execution. The t.join in the code joins the next thread to the first thread. Say if there are 2 threads with the random number generator generating 8 and 9 as integers then the main thread resumes after 17 seconds. The intent was to create threads in parallel such that the main thread resumes after the 9th second (the first thread runs completely in the first 8 seconds and then the second thread finishes execution in the next 1 second). Is it possible to create such a code by making a change to the below code?

I solved it by using a static variable which gets incremented by each thread after execution and when the thread count reaches a certain threshold we stop the execution. But is there any other way to do this ?

```
import java.util.Random;


public class ThreadsPlay {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        for(int i=3;i<12;i=i+3)
        {
            Thread t=new Thread(){

                Random r=new Random();
                int count=r.nextInt(10);

                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thread+count="+count);
                        Thread.sleep(count*1000);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            };
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of threads you've spun up, and don't join until after they've all started:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for(int i=3;i<12;i=i+3)
{
    Thread t=new Thread()
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        int count=r.nextInt(10);

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Thread+count="+count);
                Thread.sleep(count*1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}

// now wait for all threads to finish
for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

To explain the difference, I'll walk through the case you mentioned where the main method spins up two threads with `count = 8` and `count = 9`.

**Joining in first for loop (your code) - 17 seconds:**

- main method starts and enters `for`
- main starts first thread with `count=8`
- main calls `join` and blocks for 8 seconds while thread works
- first thread finishes, main re-enters `for` and starts second thread with `count=9`
- main calls `join` and blocks for 9 seconds while thread works
- second thread finishes, main finishes

**Joining in second for loop - 9 seconds:**

- main method starts and enters first `for`
- main starts first thread with `count=8`
- main re-enters first `for` and starts second thread with `count=9`
- after first `for` completes, the two threads are off and running
- main enters second `for` and calls `join` on the first thread
- main blocks for 8 seconds while *both* threads works
- first thread finishes, main re-enters second `for` and calls `join` on the second thread
- main blocks for 1 second because the 9 second thread has been working the whole time
- second thread finishes, main finishes

Now you might say, what would happen if the first thread had `count=9` and the second thread had `count=8`? When joining in a second for loop, **order does not matter, it will always be 9 seconds**:

- main enters second `for` and calls `join` on the first thread
- main blocks for 9 seconds while *both* threads works
- second thread finishes while main is waiting for first thread to finish
- first thread finishes, main re-enters second `for` and calls `join` on the second thread
- main blocks for 0 seconds because second thread has been working the whole time and already finished after 8 seconds
- main finishes

Comment: Can you please explain what happens in the for loop ?

Comment: I just updated my answer, let me know if that clears things up